# Get all records with timestamp between current day

Tags: sqlite

I want to get all records with timestamp of a current day. According to [this][1] I creating query

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN date('now', 'start of day', 'localtime', 'unixepoch') AND
                        date('now', 'start of day','+1 day', 'localtime', 'unixepoch')"
```

but allways got nothing. I updating some records calling `System.currentTimeMillis()/1000` function. I try without `unixepoch` parameter but still got nothing

EDIT: I paste my code I try to set timestamp column with diffrent types but it doesnt help too mutch

```
 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table if not exists "
        + TABLE_DAILY_CHALLENGES +
        "(" + DAILY_CHALLENGES_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        DAILY_CHALLENGES_TITLE + " text not null, "+
        DAILY_CHALLENGES_CONTENT + " text not null, "+
        DAILY_CHALLENGES_COUNTER + " text not null, "+
        DAILY_CHALLENGES_SORT+ " integer not null, " +
        DAILY_CHALLENGES_ACTUAL_COUNTER+ " text not null, " +
        DAILY_CHALLENGES_TIMESTAMP+ " integer DEFAULT 0, " +
        DAILY_CHALLENGES_FINISHED+ " integer DEFAULT 0, " +
        DAILY_CHALLENGES_TYPE + " text not null);";

   private static Database getDbHandlerInstance(){
        if(dbHandler==null){
            return init();
        }else
        return dbHandler;
    }

   private static Database init(){
    dbHandler = DatabaseFactory.getNewDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,
            DATABASE_VERSION, DATABASE_CREATE, null);

    dbHandler.setupDatabase();
    try {
        dbHandler.openOrCreateDatabase();
        dbHandler.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    } catch (SQLiteGdxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try { //TODO:: make it more efficient
        String query="SELECT * FROM dailyChallenges";
        DatabaseCursor cursor = dbHandler.rawQuery(query);
      if(cursor.getCount()!=NUMBERS_OF_RECORDS){
            cleanTable();
            populateDatabase();
    }

    } catch (SQLiteGdxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dbHandler;
}

private static void cleanTable() {
    try {
        dbHandler.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_DAILY_CHALLENGES);
    } catch (SQLiteGdxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static Challenge[] getChallenge(){

    DatabaseCursor cursor=null,cursorAll=null;
    Challenge[] challenge;

    try {
        String query="SELECT * FROM dailyChallenges WHERE timestamp BETWEEN  date('now', 'start of day', 'localtime', 'unixepoch') AND date('now', 'start of day','+1 day', 'localtime', 'unixepoch')";
        cursor = getDbHandlerInstance().rawQuery(query);
    } catch (SQLiteGdxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //create new challenge
    if(cursor.getCount()!=0){
//logic,cursor.getCount() is always 0}
```

Comment: Mysql or sqlite dont tag both database systems

Comment: What is the problem? Instead of using the `DATE()` in the where, put it on the `SELECT` until you get the values you need.

Comment: Please show the `.dump` of a suitable toy database. Info on structure, especially the timestamp column is needed.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Ive add some code, so I asumed that query is correct? I display timestamp value of all records before call getChallenge() method so I know that some records have the correct timestamp

Comment: You still haven't given any sample data that illustrates the problem.